# JSS Sitecore Form Button Submission Failed With Anti-Forgery Cookie Issue

Tags: jss, sitecore-forms, nextjs

JSS NextJS Form Component

```
import { Form } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react-forms';
import React from 'react';
import { NextRouter, withRouter } from 'next/router';
import { sitecoreApiKey } from 'temp/config';

const SitecoreForms = ({ fields, router }: { fields: any; router: NextRouter }) => {
  return (
    <Form
      language={router.locale}
      form={fields}
      sitecoreApiHost={""}
      sitecoreApiKey={sitecoreApiKey}
      onRedirect={(url) => router.push(url)}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter(SitecoreForms);
```

Added below rewrite config in the next.config.js

```
{
        source: '/api/jss/:path*',
        destination: `${jssConfig.sitecoreApiHost}/api/jss/:path*`
}
```

When I try to submit following exception occurred
[image]
[image]
[image: exception screenshot]

Installed sitecore version 10.2

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? If yes, can you share me the solution. I am facing exactly same issue. Thanks

Comment: did you find solution this ?